# Reduce dimensionality and classify EEG signals

Tags: pca, naive-bayes

I am new to machine learning, if someone could recommend a book to reduce dimensions (PCA), and classify (Naive Bayes), the purpose is to classify EEG signals, I have already applied pre-processing, (filtering, Independent Components Analysis, obtaining theta wave for features), now I try to reduce dimensions and classify.

Comment: There is much research into classifying EEGs. Check out Google Scholar and see what others have had success using.

Answer (score 0):

Hello me of 6 months ago, answered, exist a lot of tools to apply PCA,   in R `prcomp()` in python with sklearn `PCA()`, if you want an introduction I recollect these books :

https://github.com/sisifo3/PCAIntroduction/tree/main

Now, in the question of use Naive Bayes, like a personal thought, I don't think that NB could be a good method for this kind of problem, right now I'm using Deep Neural Networks Specific ResNet151 a pre-trained model in `Pytorch`